# Refresh page when window width changes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refresh a page when window width changes, I was researching and came to this code:

```js
window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }
```

It works fine but the problem is that when a user uses an android device where the address bar is hidden after a slight scroll, the page reloads (with the address bar on) then after another scroll and the address bar hidden it reloads again. So it's a perpetual reloading.

I was wondering if there's a way of doing it with window width change only.

Comment: Store the width in a variable at load and then compare it before calling the `location.reload()`

Comment: Yes, just store `window.innerWidth` in a variable and do a comparison

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to refresh the page on resize, sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and a terrible user experience

Answer (score 0):

Get the windows width at the time of page loading then on resize compare windows width to it and refresh the page

```
var w=0;
window.onload=function(){
w = window.innerWidth;
}
window.onresize = function(){ 
if(window.innerWidth!=w-10 //10 is the change of width after it refresh the page){
location.reload();
}
```